# Google Calendar. OAuth needed?

Tags: java, php, javascript, google-calendar-api

Is possible to create a Google Calendar without using OAuth to authenticate the user ? I don't need to access the user's information, only create a new calendar and display it on a webpage using the Google API.
I can use java (since I'm using the appengine), javascript, php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's enough to provide your API key: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp

You'd be on the safe side with OAuth though, and if you're using their provided client libs, it really isn't all that difficult.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

I readily admit that their documentation pages are a freaking maze though.